# Expanding a list into a dictionary in python through a transformation function returning key-value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to generate a dictionary from a list and a function that computes a key-value pair from an element of said list, such as in

```py
def transform(element):
    key = f"{element}^2"
    value = element**2
    return key, value

elements = [1, 2, 3]
elements_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in [transform(elem) for elem in elements]}

# elements_dict should be {'1^2': 1, '2^2': 4, '3^2': 9}
```

However, this list of elements can be very large and needs to be processed in a timely fashion, which makes it both impractical and inefficient to generate the intermediary array.

Is there a way to do this so that the elements are read lazily from the original list, transformed into the key value pairs by the function, and stored in the dictionary without generating any intermediary structures?

The use of the `transform` function is also non-negotiable; provided here is a minimum working sample, however they actual function is much more complex and can't simply be written as part of the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: If that's the case, why are you attempting to do this through dict comprehension? Just unravel it in a straight loop that will call your `transform` function and then use the return to update the `elements_dict` , e.g. `for elem in element: k, v = transform(elem); elements_dict[k] = v` ...

Comment: I've added some content that might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `map` function.

```
elements_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in map(transform, elements)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that probably not all of your keys will be called and you want to add `LaziNess` to your dictionary, I would suggest implementing your own class that computes the values only once they needed, something like:

```py
def transform(element):
    key = f"{element}^2"
    value = element**2
    return key, value


class LazyDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = dict()

    def get_key(self, i):
        return f"{i}^2"

    def get(self, i):
        if self.get_key(i) in self.d.keys():
            return self.d[self.get_key(i)]
        else:
            self.d.update({transform(i)})
            return self.d[self.get(i)]


d = LazyDict()
d.get(4)
# 16
```

Because if we compare the time of different implementations suggested, it is not making a huge difference

```py
import time
def transform(element):
    key = f"{element}^2"
    value = element**2
    return key, value

elements = list(range(1000000))

# Evaluating first scenario
t1 = time.time()
elements_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in [transform(elem) for elem in elements]}
t2 = time.time()
print(f'Difference 1 = {t2 - t1}')
#0.798

# Evaluating second scenario
t1 = time.time()
elements_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in map(transform, elements)}
t2 = time.time()
print(f'Difference 2 = {t2 - t1}')
#0.740
```